# Filtering `None` Field Objects With SQLAlchemy Query

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am using `SQLAlchemy` over `MySQL`.

I have a table called `DD` with a field called `tester`.

How do I find all entries with the field `tester` as `None`?

For instance, why can't I filter based on `None` like below?

```
(Pdb) x = self.session.query(DD).all()[0]
(Pdb) x.tester
(Pdb) x.tester == None
True
(Pdb) self.session.query(DD).filter(DD.tester == None).all()

[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter_by`, it worked for me:

```
self.session.query(DD).filter_by(tester=None).all()
```